# Could not load type 'Microsoft...SqlAppAuthenticationProvider' from assembly 'Microsoft...AppAuthentication'

Tags: c#, azure, azure-authentication

I am following the guide at [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi) for securing Azure SQL database connections from App Services.  I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application that references an Entity Framework 6 class library, and both projects are targetting .NET 4.7.2.

I have installed the `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication` package via NuGet (to both projects), and added the requisite Authentication Provider Config Sections and SqlAuthenticationProvider references in the web.config.

Upon starting the app, I login and as soon as a database call is made, it results in an exception:

`Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.SqlAppAuthenticationProvider' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication'.`

I have **also** tried targetting versions 4.7.1 and 4.8.  I have added conditional compilation symbols for all three versions of .NET.  None of the fixes that I have seen that work for others appear to be working for me.  In any case, the SqlAppAuthenticationProvider does not appear in the object browser.

[image: Object browser view of the Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication namespace]

Comment: Could you tell me the SDK version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, turns out the tutorial linked above actually specifies the version of the NuGet package, and it has been updated since then.  I had not paid attention to that fact when I installed the Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication package.

New version fixed the issue.

Comment: New version for me is 1.6.2 which gives this exception, installing lower version 1.6.1 fixed it

Comment: Weird enough 1.6.2 works after removing assemblyBinding for "System.Net.Http"